# Disable ScalaDoc / Javadoc in Play 2.5.x from command line using build.sbt

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, javadoc, scaladoc

What is the best way to disable scaladoc / javadoc during Activator `dist` task.

I tried the following but it did not work

```
val genDocs: java.lang.Boolean = java.lang.Boolean.getBoolean(Option(System.getProperty("genDocs")).getOrElse("true"))

import scala.Boolean

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := Boolean.unbox(genDocs)

publishArtifact in packageDoc := Boolean.unbox(genDocs)

publishArtifact in packageSrc := Boolean.unbox(genDocs)
```

I ran the `dist` as `activator  -DgenDocs=false dist` but somehow it still tries to generate documentation.

Appreciate help

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `dist` task will include the API documentation in the generated package. If this is not necessary, add these lines in `build.sbt`:

```
sources in (Compile, doc) := Seq.empty

publishArtifact in (Compile, packageDoc) := false
```

Taken from [Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production#using-the-dist-task).

Comment: I want to switch it on/off as command line parameter, I am not looking to hard code the `false` flag